# Set variables in ZSH precmd and reference them in the prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt

Is there a way to set variables in the `precmd` function of zsh and then echo them in the prompt?

Something like

```
function precmd {
   GREETING='Hi Kevin!';
}

PROMPT="$GREETING";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this in your `.zshrc`:

```
setopt prompt_subst
PROMPT='$GREETING'
```

Then `$PROMPT` will undergo parameter expansion (as well as its siblings command substitution and arithmetic expansion) each time it's displayed. Take care to quote anything that gets included from an outside source properly. Also note that the result of the `$` expansion will undergo `%` expansion (i.e. prompt escape sequences can appear in `$GREETING`).

An alternate approach is to reset the `PROMPT` variable itself in `precmd`, but this makes it harder to customize the prompt in a specific shell instance.

Comment: It turns out that having double quotes was presenting a problem. Once I changed to single quotes around the PROMPT I got the function to update fine.

Comment: Double quotes will expand $GREETING on assignment, i.e. PROMPT will be set to a fixed string. With single quotes, PROMPT will contain the _string_ $GREETING, which will then be reevaluated to the _value_ of $GREETING on every new line, thanks to prompt_subst

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. It was double quotes.

If I use single quotes instead

```
PROMPT='$(kubectl config current-context)'
```

Or, if I escape the dollar

```
PROMPT="\$(kubectl config current-context)"
```

then it works.