# pwd not being set correctly in zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt

If I type this in my PROMPT in my `.zshrc` file:

```
PROMPT="`pwd` >"
```

I expect that it will print the current working directory. However, `pwd` always prints `/Users/kevin`. Why doesn't it show my current working directory?

(I know that there is a function called `%~` that will set it for you. I'm curious why this doesn't work though, this is a simpler case of something more advanced that I'm trying to do).

Answer (score 2):

Because "pwd" gets evaluated as soon as the variable PROMPT is set. Try `echo $PROMPT`.

e.g.

```
renan ~ % PROMPT="`pwd` >"

/home/renan >echo $PROMPT
    /home/renan >
```

As you see, the "pwd" was replaced by the directory in which I was when I ran the PROMPT= command.

Comment: How can I delay execution/re-execute the function each time my PROMPT is shown?

Comment: @KevinBurke See [Set variables in ZSH precmd and reference them in the prompt](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32124)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the backticks are not substituted every magical time, but only once, so your prompt is set to whatever `pwd` you were in.  In order to reexecute something every time you enter a command, use `function precmd()` which should reset your `$PROMPT`.  For example, this is a very useful function which resets your prompt according to the current directory:

```
function windows() {
    clear
    echo -e "Microsoft Windows 2000 [Version 5.00.2195]\n(c) Microsoft Corporation, 1985-2000.\n"
    function precmd() {
        PWD=$(pwd)
        PWD=${PWD/\/usr/\/Program Files}
        PWD=${PWD/\/home\/$(whoami)/\/Documents and Settings\\Administrator}
        PWD=${PWD/\/home/\/Documents and Settings}
        PWD=${PWD/\/sbin/\/Windows}
        export PS1="C:${PWD//\//\\}> "
    }
}
```

...or just use `%~` in your PS1, like this:

```
PS1=' %n@%m: %~%# '
```

where `%n` is user, `%m` is host, `%~` is current directory and `%#` is a superuser indicator.